# Android : AdMob on canvas

Tags: java, android, admob, android-canvas, draw

I have one class where i set all Bitmaps and so on , and call class where i define Canvas adn all draw methods. thats like i draw all items , When i add AdMob i just call method to draw it from main class like this :

```
a.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(a);
    ll.setPadding(0, 50, 0, 0);
    adView = new AdView(a, AdSize.BANNER,  "my_code");  
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    adView.loadAd(request);
    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    ll.addView(adView);

    ll.draw(canvas);
}
```

});

and i don't get any error's , I set some log's and i get information that it's drawn but it didn't appears on the screen ; I tried to set visibility  and so on but it didn't help .
so how to bring to front my add or how to draw it in another way ?!

Comment: What is your logcat output?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have no ad inventory to display.
Look at your logcat output, what does Admob say.